# botão dentro de variável PHP

Tags: php

Olá,
No php há alguma forma de fazer o botão abaixo chamar a função desliga()

```
$button2 = "<input type='button' id='php_button' value='desliga' onclick='desliga()'>";
echo $button;
```

ao clicar no botão aparece o erro: Uncaught ReferenceError: desliga is not defined onclick

Explicarei melhor o que preciso.

Preciso criar alguns botões de forma dinâmica pois o número de botões pode mudar. Por exemplo pode ser que eu necessite de 5 botões com nomes diferentes que chamem a mesma função.

usando só html conforme descrito abaixo funciona, mas desse jeito eu não consigo criar os botoes de forma dinamica.
Da forma descrita abaixo o código funciona, mas o que eu quero é poder criar quantos botoes eu quiser de acordo com o resultado do num_rows de uma query sql.

```
<?PHP
function liga(){
echo "teste";
}

<input type="submit" name="liga" value="liga"/>

if (isset($_REQUEST['liga'])) {
    unset($_REQUEST['liga']);
    liga();
```

?>

Comment: É impossível fazer o que você quer da forma como você está demonstrado. Se tiver outras partes de código que ajudem esclarecer o que está tentando fazer, talvez tenha uma outra solução. Mas em geral parece ser impossível. PHP e JS são linguagens diferentes e completamente independentes.

Comment: tentei explicar melhor veja se voc~e pode me ajudar

Comment: Melhorou. Onde está esta função `liga()`? Ela está escrita em JS ou PHP? Se estiver em JS, já adianto que não é possível fazer isto. Como eu disse, as linguagens são independentes, apesar da crença popular que elas trabalham juntas. Não é fácil responder com códigos parciais. Não quer dizer que precisa colocar tudo o que você tem mas algo mínimo que possa produzir um resultado útil. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: certo, eu coloquei um exemplo de função

Comment: Ainda não dá para entender o que você quer. Fora uns erros de organização e sintaxe o que você está demonstrando funciona mas eu duvido que faça o que você quer. Se você não conseguir demonstrar o que você quer fazer, eu não conseguirei responder. Espero que outra pessoa consiga mas provavelmente será quem der o melhor chute. Veja funcionando http://ideone.com/bRPhwd. Vou repetir: se você acha que PHP e JS são a mesma linguagem, que você pode escrever tudo misturado e vai funcionar, esqueça. Se quer uma solução para o problema, descreva coerentemente o real problema.

Comment: é o típico erro dos principiantes em misturar o que é server side e client side.. Acho que um melhor caminho é orientar o Roberto a entender server-side e client-side, browser, servidores, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Em PHP é possível sim, mas você está chamando um método em javascript. O mais próximo para o que você precisa é fazer este método em javascript que fará a chamada de uma nova página onde rodará o método em PHP:

HTML:

```
<input type='button' onclick='desliga(1)'>
<input type='button' onclick='desliga(2)'>
<script>
    function desliga(id) {
        window.location.href = 'enderecoMetodoDesliga/?id='+id;
    }
</script>
```

Note que um id está sendo passado como parâmetro, assim você poderá ter vários botões na mesma página, chamando o mesmo método, diferenciando a ação por esse id.

PHP

```
desliga($_GET['id']);

function desliga($id){
    echo "teste, id: " . $id ;
}

?>
```

Considere estuar mais a respeito de requisições client-side (HTML, javascript, etc) e server-side (PHP, acesso a banco, etc). Esta solução pode ficar mais "elegante" em ajax. Considere estudar isso também.